# Backend и Frontend валидация

Tags: php, javascript, алгоритм

Как правильней будет организовать работу и валидацию а также CRUD для backend и frontend.
Backend и Frontend общаются через AJAX. То есть где-то логика такая:

FrontendForm(React.js) генерирует форму с полями, которые валидируются(Обязательные поля, диапазон значений, формат данных) и в случае успеха, отправляются к BackendForm(PHP) которые в свою очередь тоже валидируются(Обязательные поля, диапазон значений, формат данных), в случае возникновения ошибки, ответ возвращается к FrontendForm с указанием полей вызвавших их и текста ошибок. Если ошибок в форме нет. Тогда контроллер создаёт BackendModel у которого тоже есть своя валидация но уже на уровне работы с БД(Обязательные поля, тип данных, уникальность, связи)

Теперь рассмотрим несколько возможных ситуаций, которые доставляют некие сложности:

Допустим этап регистрации разбит на несколько шагов. И каждый шаг представляет из себя связку из набора BackEndForm/FrontendForm для каждого шага. И сохраняются в LocalStorage/Session, загружаются файлы и т.д. На последнем шаге данные собираются в единую форму и сохраняются в базу.

Теперь приходят правки в дизайне и поле переносится из первого шага на второй. И уже необходимо поправить валидацию и список полей в двух местах(FrontendForm и BackendForm).

Допустим клиент заходит не через браузер а через мобильное приложение, и там уже не React а что-то другое. То есть меняется только Frontend. Backend  работает по той же схеме.

Или допустим вариант когда меняется логика в backend, мы добавляем в базу еще одно поле, и следовательно поля для валидации в BackendModel, BackendForm и FrontendForm.

Кто как делает, или может есть какие-то стандарты, технологии и прочие плюшки для этого?

Чтоб из Backend формировались правила валидации для Frontend, список полей и прочее. Может быть какой-то абстрактный формат понятный как Backend так и Frontend. WSDL или вроде того.

Answer (score 1):

Помню такое решение:
На стороне Backend-а создается модель которая в себе содержит описание данных которые необходимо получить (тип, длина, обязательно ли заплнять). После чего модель передавалась FormBuilder-у который в свою очередь генерирует html и JS. При получении данных из front-end валидатору опять передается та же форма для валидации. Но это всего-лишь теория. Можешь ее реализовать либо использовать готовые решения.

-[xCrud](http://xcrud.com/)

-[Simple crud](https://github.com/oscarotero/simple-crud/blob/master/README.md)

Если ты используешь какой небудь фреймворк то скорее всего умная валидация на них будет нативно реализована ну или хотя бы на уровне расширений варианты должны быть.